# Clash between Studia Logica class file and the hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, document-classes

I have to submit the final version of a paper to Studia Logica. This means that I need to use the Studia Logica's class file `sl.cls` as well as the packages `slsec`, `stud_log`, `slfoot` and `slthm`. All this files are provided by [Studia Logica](http://www.studialogica.org/) (I can't modify them) and are available [here](http://sl.fr.pl/sl_style.zip).

I would like to use the package `hyperref`, but it seems incompatible with Studia Logica class file. For a minimal example, if I try to compile

```
\documentclass{sl}     %% This the CLASS for Studia Logica,
                       %% similar to the 'article' class.

\usepackage{slsec}     %% PACKAGES for Studia Logica
\usepackage{stud_log} 
\usepackage{slfoot}
\usepackage{slthm}     %% Theorem-like definitions as in amsthm,
                       %% see amsthdoc.tex (dvi) and thmtest.tex
                       %% for usage (see later for definitions)

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
A word.
\end{document}
```

I get the three following errors:

```
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 15.

! Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.15 \end{document}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\@secondoffive }\fi --\pageref {SLLastPage}\hfill 
! Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.15 \end{document}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! You can't use `\raise' in internal vertical mode.
\@thefoot ...\pageref {SLLastPage}\hfill }{\raise 
                                                  1.03pt\hbox {\tiny \copyri...
l.15 \end{document}

Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
```

I can't believe that it is impossible to use `hyperref`, also because there are some papers freely available online that apparently use both Studia Logica class file and `hyperref`, see for instance [here](https://link.springer.com/journal/11225/onlineFirst/page/1).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Congrats on having your paper accepted ;-) Did you try to just ask them? There is a contact at http://www.editorialmanager.com/stud/default.aspx That's probably the simplest and most efficient way to know what to do: there could be hacks to make hyperref work with their class, but that can confuse them, and they will spend time undoing what you did!

Comment: There are setting \label{SLFirstPage}  too early (with \AtBeginDocument). If one remove this, it compiles.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - It's true! If you write this in an answer I can mark my question as solved. I suppose there is no solution avoiding modifying the packages provided by Studia Logica.

Comment: @Clément - Thank you Clément. I tried to to contact them about this problem, but they gave me a generic answer: they're trying to find a solution and they'll contact later.

Comment: @Clément Errrm.. I guess, if they compile it for their journal, they will not have the modified classes. Or will you send the pdf to them?

Comment: @basseur I can't think of an editor who would accept the `pdf`, they will always ask for the source and tweak it in their own way. So, in my mind, editing the class file is a work-around, not a solution. (Private message: Hé, salut Giulio, c’est Clément !)

Comment: @Clément That's what I mean. It would only work for Giulio.

Comment: @basseur So I guess your message was for Ulrike, and not me, then `:-)`.

Comment: Someone should call them and ask to remove their faulty lines in their class file at their end. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class file sets a  `\label{SLFirstPage}` too early (with `\AtBeginDocument`).

If one remove this, it compiles.